# Problem installing build-essential in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install `build-essential` but Ubuntu cannot find it.

```
ruchir@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package build-essential
```

Comment: Which repositories do you have enabled in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Answer (score 2):

Try updating first

`sudo apt-get update`

and then try to install it

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`